# Laravel - daterangepicker with Ajax returns status of 500 internal server error

Tags: ajax, laravel, daterangepicker

So I add daterangepicker with Ajax on my Laravel project, on my blade I have daterangepicker like a calendar to chose date and also refresh and filter.Now when I click refresh it refreshes me currently picked date but when I do filter nothing happens.When I Inspect Element on my Safari browser it shows me: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Here is my DateRangeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Post;
use Auth;

class DateRangeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id());
        return view('daterange')->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    public function fetch_data(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '')
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')
         ->whereBetween('date', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
         ->get();
      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
     }
    }
}

?>
```

Here is my daterange.blade.php with script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Date Range Fiter Data in Laravel using Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container box">
   <h3 align="center">Date Range Fiter Data in Laravel using Ajax</h3><br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">Sample Data - Total Records - <b><span id="total_records"></span></b></div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
       <div class="input-group input-daterange">
           <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" readonly class="form-control" />
           <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
           <input type="text"  name="to_date" id="to_date" readonly class="form-control" />
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
       <button type="button" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Filter</button>
       <button type="button" name="refresh" id="refresh" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Refresh</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th width="35%">Broj Kesice</th>
         <th width="50%">Ime</th>
         <th width="15%">Broj Telefona</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$post->br_kesice}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->ime}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->br_telefona}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
       </tbody>
      </table>
      {{ csrf_field() }}
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var date = new Date();

 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  todayBtn: 'linked',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true
 });

 var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

 fetch_data();

 function fetch_data(from_date = '', to_date = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('daterange.fetch_data') }}",
   method:"POST",
   data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, _token:_token},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var output = '';
    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
    for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
    {
     output += '<tr>';
     output += '<td>' + data[count].post_br_kesice + '</td>';
     output += '<td>' + data[count].post_ime + '</td>';
     output += '<td>' + data[count].date + '</td></tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(output);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#filter').click(function(){
  var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
  var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
  if(from_date != '' &&  to_date != '')
  {
   fetch_data(from_date, to_date);
  }
  else
  {
   alert('Both Date is required');
  }
 });

 $('#refresh').click(function(){
  $('#from_date').val('');
  $('#to_date').val('');
  fetch_data();
 });


});
</script>
```

And here are my routes for daterange

```
Route::get('/daterange', 'DateRangeController@index');
Route::post('/daterange/fetch_data', 'DateRangeController@fetch_data')->name('daterange.fetch_data');
```

Any solutions to this problem? It needs to show me posts from selected date

Comment: The reason could be some, but first, try to return the controller answer and do not echo it out: `return json_encode($data);` Better would be `return response()->json(['type' => 'success', 'data' => $data])`

Comment: What is the request url in network  devtools,when you do the action?

Comment: I did ```return json_encode($data);``` and ```return response()->json(['type' => 'success', 'data' => $data]);``` but nothing happens, its stay the same..

Comment: When I do the action it returns me 
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` order by `date` desc)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/monokl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 664,
    "trace": [ ...

Comment: Ouu , I just fixed it, in url request it said unknown column date and I fixed it with created_at and its working. But now the problem is it returns me Undefined in <table> for posts

Comment: So my function in DateRangeController now is like this
```
public function fetch_data(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '')
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')
         ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
         ->get();
      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      }
      return json_encode($data);
     }
    }
}
```
but right now it return me nothing when I click filter

Comment: Add console.log(data) in success:function
check if there is a response!

Comment: But I think I don't have success:function...

Comment: In the ajax....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it all to created_at, not date and now my DateRangeController looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Post;
use Auth;

class DateRangeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id());
        return view('daterange')->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    public function fetch_data(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      if($request->from_created_at != '' && $request->to_created_at != '')
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')
         ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_created_at, $request->to_created_at))
         ->get();
      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      }
      return json_encode($data);
     }
    }
}

?>
```

it returns me now all posts but it like undefined, and on network url request it returns me the real ones, not undefined. Any solutions?

Comment: it should be  if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '')
      as you sent in the request data 
   data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, _token:_token}
and change also in the query in "whereBetween"

Comment: yea I changed it, but when I change it shows me nothing when I select some date, but when I refresh it shows me all 14 posts, but it shows me like undefined for every posts->br_kesice, $post->ime...

Comment: Can you upload project on github?!

Comment: I'll do it in a minute

Comment: plz ,upload your database sql file

Comment: How can i upload it, i uploaded whole project using initital commit in microsoft visual and the github commands for pulling up project

Comment: Add sql data  file to project files then add and commit and  push

Comment: ```php artisan db:seed ``` ?

Comment: Check my  new answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in success function,
you try handle property not found,
this is the full script tag

```
<script>
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $(document).ready(function(){

 var date = new Date();

 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  todayBtn: 'linked',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true
 });


 //if you leave this ,will load the data if you remove this  remove comment  from line number 43 to 49 to load data :)
        fetch_data();


 $('#filter').click(function(){
  var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
  var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
  if(from_date != '' &&  to_date != '')
  {
   fetch_data(from_date, to_date);
  }
  else
  {
   alert('Both Date is required');
  }
 });

 $('#refresh').click(function(){
  $('#from_date').val('');
  $('#to_date').val('');
  fetch_data();
 });


});
function fetch_data(from_date = '', to_date = '')
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('daterange.fetch_data') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, _token:_token},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var output = '';
            $('#total_records').text(data.length);
            $.each(data,function (key,value) {
                console.log(value)
                output += '<tr>';
                output += '<td>' + value.br_kesice + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + value.ime + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + value.created_at + '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('tbody').html(output);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Remove the repository,
good luck with your project :)